# How to set opacity to background-image

Tags: html, css

I want to set a `background-image` of `50% opacity` to my HTML page. Following is the code
that I wrote:

CSS:

```
body{background-image:"E:\\Work\HTML5\IMG_18072014_115640.png"}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<body>
   The background image is known shown.
</body>
```

But I cannot see any background image. But the image shows if I use this:

HTML:

```
<body background="IMG_18072014_115640.png">The background is shown.</body>
```

Why does the first code not show any background image but the second code does. I want my background image to be shown in the way written in first code.

Comment: `background-image:"E:\\Work\HTML5\IMG_18072014_115640.png"` is invalid syntax. You should read through this article. ---> http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `url` part, here is the syntax

```
 background-image: url('img/whatever.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the url part:

```
background-image: url('img/name-of-image.png');
```

This code is from [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/). You can try it!

```
body {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url('./img/name-of-image.jpg');
  opacity: 0.5; /* 0.5 = 50% */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```